# REPLACE INTO not affecting any rows

Tags: java, mysql

I have the following code:

```
manager.prepareStatement("REPLACE INTO `players` SELECT `id`, `uuid`, ?, ?, `date`"
                + " FROM `players` WHERE `uuid` = ? AND `date` = ?;");
        manager.addString(1, ...);
        manager.addString(2, ...);
        manager.addString(3, uuid.toString());
        manager.addLong(4, ...);
        logger.debug("Updated " + manager.update() + " rows");
        manager.commit();
        manager.closeStatement();
```

I have also done the following before:

```
ALTER TABLE `players` ADD CONSTRAINT `uuid_date` UNIQUE ( `uuid`, `date` );
```

REPLACE INTO should replace if an existing row is found and otherwise insert. I would expect that this will always affect at least 1 row. However, for some reason nothing happens and it tells me 0 rows were affected. How is this possible?

EDIT: I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50950903/unique-constraints-insert-or-update-for-both-mysql-and-sqlite). I think the problem is that it won't insert if the SELECT doesn't find anything, but how do I work around that?

Note: `manager` is an instance of a custom class I use to handle exceptions.

Comment: You cannot bind into column names. Hardcode a whitelist and place them into the query directly

Comment: not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: `REPLACE INTO \`players\` SELECT \`id\`, \`uuid\`, ?, ?,\`date\`` Right here the two `?` are column names. It's a limitation of SQL that you cannot use prepare/bind on a column name.

Comment: They are not column names, they are values I insert. Like if I were to place them into the query directly it'd look like ```... `uuid`, 'foo', 'bar', `date` ```

Comment: MySQL thinks those are column names as it's within the `SELECT`

Comment: No. You can just use ```SELECT `column_name`, 'just a string', `other_column` ``` in MySQL.

Comment: `PreparedStatements.getWarnings()` might be interesting to log in your manager.

Comment: Not getting any warnings

Answer (score -1):

It is a correct usage of preparedstatements:

```
@Override
public long write(Connection con) throws SQLException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String batchQuery = "INSERT INTO " + ResultSchema.ID.getTableName() +
            " (" + ResultSchema.URL.getColumnName() + "," +
            ResultSchema.SE_TITLE.getColumnName() +
            ") VALUES (?,?)";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(batchQuery);

    preparedStatement.setString(1, this.getUrl());
    preparedStatement.setString(2, this.getSeTitle());
    preparedStatement.addBatch();

    return preparedStatement.executeBatch()[0];
}
```

you should call execute or executeBatch to apply your query on database.